# Failed to retrieve Google leaderboard scores

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am creating a game in which I am implementing google play game services.
My sign in process is working fine and achievement too. but there is a slightly some issue with the leaderboard. Here is the error I am getting,

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400
```

com.android.volley.ClientError
                                                        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms:34)
                                                        at mao.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms:3)
                                                        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:com.google.android.gms:11)

Comment: AFAIK, response code 400 are usually encountered if there are required field or parameter that hasn't been provided, the value supplied is invalid, or the combination of provided fields is invalid.

Comment: You may want to see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306096/cant-retrieve-leaderboard) and this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards). See if it will help you.